# Scripting actions in go project

Tags: go

I want to make some simple scripts in a web of mine written in go: things like a script to run database migrations, generate alert dashboards etc.

I'm wondering what the best method is for doing this. Ideally the scripts would be in the same project, but since I can only have one main method this seems a little difficult.

Options I think I have:

1) have a param to the server binary so I can run something like ./server SETUP (the command)

2) put these scripts in a different repo (Some of the code is pretty specific to the current project)

Is there some standard way to do this in go?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html shows how you can have multiple binaries in one workspace (see `hello` and `outyet` in the example workspace). It's not clear to me exactly what you mean by "project" -- but I guess you just want a bunch of binaries in subdirs of your project's top level directory.